# Argmax in $k$-NN algorithm

Tags: machine-learning

> Given a query instance $x_q$ to be classified
>
> - Let $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ be $k$ instances which are nearest to $x_q$
>   $$ \hat{f}(x_q) \gets \operatorname*{argmax}_{v \in V} \sum_{i=1}^k \delta(v,f(x_i)), $$
>   where $\delta(a,b)=1$ if $a=b$, else $\delta(a,b)=0$ (Kronecker function).

If $f$ is an objective function to be optimized, why is argmax there? Can someone explain how this function gets updated. This is for $k$-nearest neighbor function.

Comment: What's the source where you encountered that equation?  What is the surrounding context?  What is the meaning of all of the variables?  We can't answer this question in isolation.

Comment: On top of what @D.W. said, you should especially explain all of the symbols (e.g. $x_q$, $V$, and $\delta$). Gradient descent is usually formulated in terms of the gradient of the objective function, hence the name.

Comment: @D.W. its the objective function of K-nearest neighbor

Comment: I don't see any gradient descent here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus oh yeah there is no gradient descent here. But how is gradient descent used in approximate k nearest neighbor search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a new point $x_q$, we find the $k$ closest points $x_1,\ldots,x_k$. Each one of them is associated with a cluster $f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_k)$. We assign $x_q$ to the most common cluster among $f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_k)$. The argmax equation is just a fancy way of expressing this idea: for any cluster $v$, the quantity $\sum_{i=1}^k \delta(v,f(x_i))$ is just the number of $x_i$'s which are assigned to cluster $v$, and the argmax picks up the cluster $v$ maximizing this parameter.